# Conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type assignment operator - object to int

Tags: c++, type-conversion, overloading, operator-keyword, implicit-conversion

I have a problem with assignment int to object like this:

```
int main() {
     Wurzel a;  
     Wurzel b=3; // error: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'Wurzel' requested

     return 0;
}
```

My class with assignment operator:

```
class Wurzel{
private:
    int wurzelexponent;
    int wert;

public:

    Wurzel(){
        wurzelexponent=1;
        wert=1;
    }

    Wurzel& operator =(const Wurzel &w)  {

        wurzelexponent = w.wurzelexponent;

    }
};
```

I must do this with `=` operator

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I must do this with = operator

No, you can't. Because `Wurzel b=3;` is not assignment, it's initialization, [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). As the error message said, you need a [converting constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) to accomplish it.

```
class Wurzel{
    ...
public:
    ...
    Wurzel(int x) : wurzelexponent(x), wert(1) {}
    Wurzel(int x, int y) : wurzelexponent(x), wert(y) {}
    ...
};
```

then

```
Wurzel b = 3;      // Wurzel::Wurzel(int) will be called
Wurzel b = {3, 2}; // Wurzel::Wurzel(int, int) will be called [1]
```

Note that `operator=` is only used for assignment, such as:

```
Wurzel b;      // default initialized
b = something; // this is assignment, operator=() will be used
```

---

<sup>[1] Converting constructor with multiple parameters was introduced from C++11.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assing an int: `Wurzel b=3;`, but your operator= is only overloaded for `const Wurzel &w`. Its parameter is `Wurzel`, not an int and int is not implicitly convertible to `Wurzel`. To fix, you can add another operator:

```
Wurzel& operator =(int i)
{}
```

Comment: No, not `operator=` but a constructor will be called for `Wurzel b=3;`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that functions needed are not defined.

One solution is overloading `=` operator to accept `int`.

Try this:

```
class Wurzel{
private:
    int wurzelexponent;
    int wert;

public:

    Wurzel(){
        wurzelexponent=1;
        wert=1;
    }
    // this is constructor, not = operator
    /*
    Wurzel(int a) {
        wurzelexponent = a;
        wert = a;
    }
    */

    Wurzel& operator =(const Wurzel &w)  {

        wurzelexponent = w.wurzelexponent;
        return *this; // you should return something

    }
    Wurzel& operator=(int a) {
        // implement as you like
        wurzelexponent = a;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    Wurzel a;
    // this is not = operator but initializing
    //Wurzel b=3;

    Wurzel b;
    b = 3; // this is = opetator, which you say you must use

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but why I can't use `Wurzel b=3`? I can not be assignment directly? For your solution  my operator is needed? `Wurzel& operator =(const Wurzel &w)`

Comment: You can *initialize* (by calling constructor) directly, but cannot do *assignment* (using assignment operator) directly. `Wurzel b=3;` can be done by defining proper constructor, but you saiid you must use `=` operator, so you must use it somewhere -- maybe in the definition of the constructor? Your operator isn't needed in this program.

Comment: Definition of the constructor? What do you mean exactly? The problem is that in class I have two variables, and then I have to somehow distinguish them if I initiates them separately.

Comment: @lukassz Based on that last comment I think you may have accidentally asked the wrong question. Are you trying to set both `wurzelexponent` and `wert;` to different values at the same time?

Comment: Yes, eg. `wurzelexponent = 2`, and `wert = 5`